# how to make charts and graphs in CiviCRM

Tags: reports, custom-reports

I was wondering if it is possible through in CiviCRM, WordPress to do charts or graphs. If so, how should I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to extend what [CiviVisualise](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civisualize-missing-data-visualization-extension) extension provides